# ObjectDataSource typename of a singleton Business object

Tags: asp.net

How do I make ObjectDataSource work with singleton Business object?

My singleton business object is defined in Global:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
        public static BusinessForm BusinessFormLayer;            

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                        
            FormDalProvider concreteProvider = FormDalProvider.Instance;
            BusinessForumLayer = new BusinessForum(concreteProvider);
        }
}
```

My page:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objThreads" runat="server"                       
                      SelectMethod="GetForms"
                      SelectCountMethod="GetFormsCount"
                      TypeName="Global.BusinessFormLayer"
                      EnablePaging="true" 
                      SortParameterName="sortExpression">
```